# Как вызвать функцию в приходящий json? Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular2

Здравствуйте!

Имеется вот такая функция по конвертации чисел из байт в килобайты, мегабайты и т.д

```
bytesToSize(bytes, decimals) {
    if(bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
    var k = 1000; 
    var dm = decimals + 1 || 3;
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'Kb', 'Mb', 'Gb', 'Tb', 'Pb', 'Zb', 'Yb'];
    var i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k,i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];  
}
```

Вопрос собственно таков, как в такую вот форму,

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" *ngFor="let list of lists">
      <caption>{{list.nodename}}</caption>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>MountPoint</th>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th>Used</th>
              <th>Free</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let service_rec of list.storagelist">
              <td>{{ service_rec.mountpoint }}</td>
              <td>{{ service_rec.total }}</td>
              <td>{{ service_rec.used }}</td>
              <td>{{ service_rec.free }}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

вызвать данную функцию?

Поясню, в таблицу приходят числовые значения (в данном случае байты):

```
 <tr *ngFor="let service_rec of list.storagelist">
          <td>{{ service_rec.mountpoint }}</td>
          <td>{{ service_rec.total }}</td>
          <td>{{ service_rec.used }}</td>
          <td>{{ service_rec.free }}</td>
      </tr>
```

[image: более наглядно можно взглянуть здесь]

как правильно вставить данную функцию, чтобы она автоматически конвертировала все числа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой задачи хорошо подходят [pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)

Пример из документации с передачей параметра (без параметра будет еще проще):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
/*
 * Raise the value exponentially
 * Takes an exponent argument that defaults to 1.
 * Usage:
 *   value | exponentialStrength:exponent
 * Example:
 *   {{ 2 |  exponentialStrength:10}}
 *   formats to: 1024
*/
@Pipe({name: 'exponentialStrength'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent: string): number {
    let exp = parseFloat(exponent);
    return Math.pow(value, isNaN(exp) ? 1 : exp);
  }
}
```

В шаблоне вызывается так:

```
<p>Super power boost: {{2 | exponentialStrength: 10}}</p>
```